# How can I prevent a main menu item with sub items from being clickable in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem

Here is my site:
http://wake9.com/blogs/norcal-merced-wakesurfing-competition-2009/.

Notice the menu item "Photos and Results". Hover over it and you will see sub menu items. I want to be able to click on the sub-menu items but the main menu item shouldn't be a page or be clickable. The only way i could get this item on the menu was to make it a page. Is there a way to just have a menu item that has sub menu items to content, but the actual menu item isn't clickable? I was thinking about using JQuery to remove the anchor tag, but that is a real hack and I want to know if there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use [Page Links to](http://txfx.net/code/wordpress/page-links-to/) plugin and set the main link as '**#**' . I tried this and it works in my blog.

Comment: great answer! this is exactly what i needed with no hacking. I'm new to WP so i'm not familiar with all of the popular plug-ins the kids are using these days :) thanks!

Comment: If you write a non-existent anchor after `#` (like `#menu10`), the click shouldn't scroll the user up to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [jQuery.remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) to remove the  element?

something like this:

```
function removeLinkAttrib() {
  var attrib =  jQuery(#menus).find("a").attr("Photos and Results");
  jQuery(attrib).remove;
}
```

I'm not sure if **$(attrib).remove;** will work, but you get the picture :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i wanted to avoid using a hack. One of the issues that i was having was when i would try to reference a js file that had jquery in it, it would be inserted into the html BEFORE jquery.js... so as you would expect, i would get a js error because $ or jQuery wasn't defined.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

(this answer is for people using Wordpress.com free sites):

You can go to Appearance > Menus, then add a custom link to the menu by clicking 'Links' in the left-hand column, and adding "#" as the URL (and whatever you want as a label).  Then add this link to the menu.  Open the options for the new menu item in 'Menu Structure', and then delete '#' from the URL, so the field is blank, and save changes.  Now you can add sub-menus to this menu item, and there will be no link for this item on the main menu...works for me.