# WordPress: How to prevent toplevel menu-items to be a link?

Tags: wordpress

How can I prevent toplevel menu-items of a WordPress menu to be a link?

See for example this website: http://thesoftworld.com/

So "about" should not be a link, but "about > philosophy" should be. Also items with no subitems (e.g. "film") should be a link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a top-level navigation item to act as a trigger for a drop down menu, but not actually link anywhere, here’s how to do it in the WordPress menu system:

1. Insert a custom link with a label and any link address
2. Click on Edit Menu Item link (triangle)
3. Delete link address in URL field
4. Add nested sub-menu items
5. Save

Comment: Great! This works. I also found out there is a difference between an empty URL and a "#". By using a # it's still a link but noting happens after clicking it (what was in principal not my question but what is what I want), by using an empty URL there's no link, but it looks a bit different, for example you can select the text. So I decided to use a #. It's up to you

Comment: Yes, alink to # will still be a link. The user can click it. Glad I can help.

Comment: Using # for the HREF may cause problems for SPA designs or any design that uses # for other reasons.  In that case, might just use CSS to get the pointer cursor.  Something like: .menu-item a {cursor: pointer;}

Answer (score 1):

There exist a plugin to do the task:
[Link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-parent-menu-link/)

And you can do it manually by setting its **HREF="#"** in  the Code of the HTML Page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "by setting its HREF="#" in the Code of the HTML Page"?

Answer (score 0):

I also found this:

[How can I prevent a main menu item with sub items from being clickable in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887464/how-can-i-prevent-a-main-menu-item-with-sub-items-from-being-clickable-in-wordpr?rq=1)

Almost exactly the same question. Sorry for duplicating questions.